# 'UI-Kitten' Select Component not rendering value

Tags: react-native, formik, react-native-ui-kitten

I am using react naitve with `UI-kitten` and `formik` to build a registration form. I am using select component of `ui kitten` inside `formik`. I am not been able to get the selected value from the component. It gives me the index of the selected item `(in console.warn())` and the selected item does't appear in the field. It works fine with input and `datePicker` component.

```
    const formSchema = yup.object({
    name: yup.string().required("*Full Name is required"),
    gender: yup.string().required("*Gender is required"),
    dob: yup.string().required("*Date of birth is required"),})

    export default class Registration extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Formik
                validationSchema={formSchema}
                initialValues={{
                    name: '',
                    gender: '',
                    dob: '',
                }}
                onSubmit={(values) => {
                    console.log(values)
                }}
            >
                {(props) => (

                    <ScrollView style={styles.containerStyle}>
                        <LinearGradient style={{ height: '100%' }}
                            colors={["#0C1248", "#D03737"]}>
                            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewStyle}>
                                <Text style={styles.textStyle} category='h2'>Registration</Text>
                                <Input
                                    style={styles.inputView}
                                    value={props.values.name}
                                    status='primary'
                                    placeholder="Full Name"
                                    onChangeText={props.handleChange('name')}
                                />

                                <Text style={styles.errorText}>{props.touched.name && props.errors.name}</Text>

                                <Datepicker
                                    style={styles.inputView}
                                    date={props.values.dob}
                                    placeholder="Date of birth"
                                    onSelect={(dob) => { props.setFieldValue('dob', dob) }}
                                />

                                <Text style={styles.errorText}>{props.touched.dob && props.errors.dob}</Text>

                                <Select
                                    style={styles.inputView}
                                    value={props.values.gender}
                                    placeholder='Gender'
                                    onSelect={item => props.setFieldValue(
                                       'gender', item.value
                                    )}
                                >
                                    <SelectItem title='Male' />
                                    <SelectItem title='Female' />
                                </Select>

                              

                                <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                                    <LinearGradient style={{ width: width / 1.25, padding: 12, borderRadius: 30 }}
                                        colors={["#D03737", "#0C1248"]}>
                                        <Text style={{ color: "white", textAlign: "center" }} onPress={props.handleSubmit}>Next</Text>
                                    </LinearGradient>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </ScrollView>
                        </LinearGradient>
                    </ScrollView>

                )}
            </Formik>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer the documentation
https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/select/overview#select

The select component doenst have a value prop, it has a selectedIndex props which will chose the item on the given index.

In your case you can do something like this

```js
<Select
    style={styles.inputView}
    value={props.values.gender}
    placeholder='Gender'
    onSelect={item => props.setFieldValue(
    'gender', item.row == 0 ? 'Male' : 'Female'
    )}
    >
    <SelectItem title='Male' />
    <SelectItem title='Female' />
</Select>
```

Based on the state value you can find the index and vise versa. This will make sure that Select always getting an index value and your state always having a string.

Comment: I tried this. But it gives me an error - selectedIndex.equals is not a function. (In 'selectedIndex.equals(index)', 'selectedIndex.equals' is undefined)

Comment: is 'selectedIndex.equals' part of your code or it something from the library itself ?

Comment: ok found it, you have to use React.useState(new IndexPath(0)); check that page i have given

Comment: i am using class component so i cant use react hooks

Comment: But you will have to use the new IndexPath(0) as the default value

Comment: i tried to add that in the initial values inside the formik and then use onSelect as you showed before but it gives me the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223972/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-zaid-mohammad).

Answer (score 2):

I created the function "getSelectValue" which handles this for multi- and single select. Here is the slightly modified [example code](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/select/overview#select) from UIKittenDocs for a Multiselect but you can just remove the property from the Select component for Singleselect.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { IndexPath, Layout, Select, SelectItem } from '@ui-kitten/components';

export const TAGS = [
  'Handwerk',
  'Bio',
  'Vegetarisch',
  'Vegan',
  'Glutenfrei',
  'Laktosefrei',
  'Natürlich'
];

function getSelectValue(selectedIndexPaths, options) {
  if (selectedIndexPaths.length) {
    // multiSelect
    return selectedIndexPaths
    .map((indexPath) => options[indexPath.row])
    .join(', ');
  } else {
    // singleSelect
    return options[selectedIndexPaths.row]
  }
}

export const SelectMultiSelectShowcase = () => {

  const [selectedTags, setSelectedTags] = React.useState([
    new IndexPath(0),
    new IndexPath(1),
  ]);

  return (
    <Layout style={styles.container} level='1'>
      <Select
        value={getSelectValue(selectedTags, TAGS)}
        multiSelect
        selectedIndex={selectedTags}
        onSelect={setSelectedTags}
      >
        {TAGS.map((tag, index) => 
          <SelectItem key={index} title={tag} />
        )}
      </Select>
    </Layout>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: 128,
  },
});
```